# Prevent multiple views from sharing the same model data

Tags: model, sapui5

I have a page in my application and an associated controller. For example `A.view.xml` and `A.controller.js`.

One of the other programmers has a requirement to create a similar page. So he copied my page's view and controller (and changed the file names to B). This new page which he created is being called from another location in the application.

The issue is: 
When I open page A, fill it with some data, cancel/save it, and then go to page B and open it, this page opens with the same data as I populated in page A.

I believe this has to do with the fact that both pages have the same design, the same IDs, and even the same model name. How do I prevent the data from flowing from page A to page B? I can not back out of page B.

Comment: Can you share your **view**  and **controller** code for both?

Comment: You need a shared Model between the 2 views. One 'easy' way to do that is to declare the model in a common parent view (views inherit from their parent's models)

Comment: @JiaSH I think he wants the opposite of that, because right now he has a shared model but wants the two views to be independent.

Comment: maybe i misunderstood the question then :p

Comment: Can you show where/how you create your model and where you set it? On what control do you call your `setModel`? Are the models created by the controller of each view or somewhere externally?

Answer (score 0):

Why you aren't using different models?

A.view.xml

```
<Page id="pageA">
```

B.view.xml

```
<Page id="pageB">
```

A.controller.js

```
init: function(){
    var oModelA = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    this.getView().byId("pageA").setModel(oModelA, "ModelA");
}
```

B.controller.js

```
init: function(){
    var oModelB = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    this.getView().byId("pageB").setModel(oModelB, "ModelB");   
}
```